# Where is atrace.c located?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools, systrace

I am trying to write a script to get frame rate data using systrace.

I know that systrace calls atrace. But I can't find out where atrace.c is located. Is it within the sdk or within the kernel? Either way it does not exist in msm kernel or the latest android sdk.

Google's git repo shows it is here

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/android-sdk-support_r11/atrace/atrace.c

Yet I haven't  cloned that repo.

So I am not sure where systrace is calling atrace from

the adb shell command that I am running is

```
$>atrace gfx
```

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the platform code.  The latest version is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/cmds/atrace/atrace.cpp).  Note that it changed from `.c` to `.cpp`.